# Alfresco Custom Data List Type Text Field Help Text

Tags: forms, alfresco, ecm

I've successfully created a new Data List type in Alfresco, but was struggling to figure out what the tag is called to achieve a description under a field. I consulted the [Data Dictionary](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Data_Dictionary_Guide#Data_Types), but was unable to find it.

It may not exist, but the [this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SHPoh.png) makes me hopeful. As you can see, the **Modified Date** field has the *DD/MM/YYYY* help text under it. This is exactly what I want to put under the **Program Name** field, but with my own string.

```html
<property name="orpdl:programName">
  <title>Program Name</title>
  <type>d:text</type>
  <helptext>What's this tag called?</helptext>
  <mandatory>true</mandatory>
</property>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eeuh that's just a div in the control field for all the date fields.

Take a look at **alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/form/controls/date.ftl**

The message you see is in this div:

```
<div class="format-info">
            <span class="date-format">${msg("form.control.date-picker.display.date.format")}</span>
            <#if showTime><span class="time-format<#if disabled>-disabled</#if>">${msg("form.control.date-picker.display.time.format")}</span></#if>
         </div>
```

So you want a string, just create your own custom controller based on **textfield.ftl** and put whatever string you like. Probably best to do that by passing it through the **control-params**.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Could you either briefly explain how to achieve the last part of your answer, or direct me to a resource? Alfresco is a very new platform for me.

Comment: Hi Alan, there are tons of tutorials how to create a custom control & supply control parameters. So i'm not going to copy paste that or do the search for you :)

Comment: I almost have this completed, however, I don't know how to define a new variable: field.control.params.helptext to pass into the div. Where can I define this?